# How to select rows from the same table that have only unique value in some column using JOINs?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have table Apples with three columns

```
Id Color Price
```

And this data in table

```
+----+-----------+------+
| Id | Color     | Price| 
+----+-----------+------+
| 1  | Red       | 5    | 
| 2  | Red       | 1    |  
| 3  | Green     | 3    |
| 4  | Orange    | 4    |
+----+-----------+------+-
```

In resulting table I want to see:

```
+----+-----------+------+
| Id | Color     | Price| 
+----+-----------+------+
| 3  | Green     | 3    |
| 4  | Orange    | 4    |
+----+-----------+------+
```

How do I do this using joins without sub-queries?

At this point I have this query that selects only Red apples:

```
select *
from apples as a1
left join apples as a2
on a1.Id != a2.Id
where a1.Color = a2.Color;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspired by India.Rocket:

```
select A.Id, A.Color, A.Price
     from Apples A
     left join Apples A2 on A2.Color= A.Color and A2.Id<>A.Id
     where A2.Id is null
     group by A.Id, A.Color, A.Price
```

Answer (score 1):

Modified your query a bit. Query with only 1 `left join`and not `subqueries` or `having` clause and will work in most of the databases

Check this out.

```
select distinct a1.*
from apples as a1
inner join apples as a2
on a1.Color < a2.Color;
```

OR

```
select distinct a1.*
from apples as a1
inner join apples as a2
on a1.Id > a2.Id
where a1.Color != a2.Color;
```

Hope this helps:-)

Comment: Your second one doesn't work for me as soon as there's a duplicate with higher Id (e.g: add another `Red` with Id `5`). The first one seems to work fine and it's pretty clever :-)

Comment: That's what i thought and that's why i gave 2 solutions

Comment: tried it using mysql 5.7 and it doesn't work... just selects all records

Comment: That's might be because 'not null' condition is not working for you. I have now used inner join instead of left join which eliminates the  need of 'not null' condition. Wanted to keep my query as close as possible to your query, that's why didn't use inner join earlier

Comment: I didn't try your changes in MySql 5.7, but it works only if table has one same color on multiple rows. When there is more then one same colors, for instance red, red, orange, orange it selects orange with duplicates. I suggested my solution as answer.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a `join` for that... something like this should work:

```
SELECT *
FROM apples
GROUP BY Color
HAVING COUNT(*)=1
```

[I made a fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d60c25/1)

Comment: But, can I do this only using joins or without using HAVING or sub-queries?

Comment: @MilanŠvec check the working fiddle... seems to work on mySql... I was pretty sure it didn't on T-SQL but checked and it worked on mySql

Comment: @MaxNaumov I don't think so without using subqueries

Comment: @Jcl No, you can't, it is matematically wrong. I can not run your fiddle, I just tested it in my database.

Comment: @MilanŠvec what can I say... [seems to work for me](https://i.imgur.com/ChWd5IK.png)

Comment: @Jcl - this is mysql's issue

Comment: I just tested it on a real mysql (not fiddle) and it works too... so it seems to work on MySQL (and the question is tagged `mysql`). [Here's another screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/1vZXcvn.png), running on MariaDB 10.1

Comment: @Jcl Asterix* contains also columns (id, price) that can have multiple values for each row after grouping. MySql of sqlfiddle uses something like FIRSTVALUE(columnname) or ANYVALUE(columnname) to shrinken it to only one value. Or there may be some optimalization in MySql that sees, that it can not happen when "having count(*) = EXACTLY 1". MS SQL correctly issues an error. I can not post it here, my SQL engine is in Czech language, but you can google the error message: "Column is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the group by clause"

Comment: @Jcl OK, the question is tagger MySql, you are right in such case.

Comment: @MilanŠvec yes, as I said, I'm pretty sure it doesn't work on T-SQL (SQL Server)

Answer (score 0):

Inner query: Select all colors that have only one occurence, when you group them together. Outer query: Select all apples where color is one of the colors selected by inner query.

```
select * from Apples 
    where Color in (
        select Color from Apples group by Color having count(*)=1
    )
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you would edit the answer to describe more about how this works. Also, the OP asked for a solution without a subquery.

Comment: How does it work? Inner query: Select all colors that have only one occurence, when you group them together. Outer query: Select all apples where color is one of the colors selected by inner query. For other solutions see other answers.

Comment: Apparently, I can. I believe you could too.

Answer (score 0):

Or using ONLY joins:

```
select Apples.* 
    from Apples
    inner join 
    (
        select Color from Apples group by Color having count(*)=1
    ) colors on colors.Color=Apples.Color
```

Comment: there is sub-query, I want to avoid them.

Comment: You can't. Subquery or temporary table is needed for this type of query. Why do you need to avoid it?

Comment: Or use solution with IN() in my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

This query works in sqlfiddle and in MySql 5.7.

First I join tables to select rows with duplicate colors. Then I join the result table and remove the duplicates from the table.

```
select a1.*
from apples as a1
left join apples as a2
on (a1.Id <> a2.Id and a1.Color = a2.Color)
left join apples a3
on (a2.Color is null and a1.Id = a3.Id)
where a3.Color is not null;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/23df971/1

Comment: joining a3 has no sense. left join will never remove duplicates. you can directly modify last line to "where a2.Color is not null", look at my another solution